# C# /Linq Yet another Brain Teaser

Tags: c#, linq

Friends, there is yet another scenario to solve. I am working it out without applying Linq.But I hope it is good opportunity for me to learn Linq if you share your code in Linq.

It is know as  **FLAMES**

**F      - Friend**

L      - Lover

A     -  Admirer

M    -   Marry(Husband)

E     -  Enemy

S     -  Sister

**Problem description:**

Two names will be given (male, female).We have to strike out the common letters from both names. Then we have to count  the number of remaining letters after striking out the common characters from both names. Finally we have to iterate the string FLAMES and striking out the letters in FLAMES until we will reach single character left. The remaining single character shows the relationship. I will explain the process more details   in the following example.(Ignore cases and spaces).

Example :

**Step 1**

```
Male    : Albert

Female : Hebarna
```

Letters  “a”, “e” ,”b” are common in both names.

( Strike those letters from both string , even the name “Hebarna” contains two “a” you are allowed to strike single “a” from both string because The name “Albert” has only single “a”).

The resultant string is

```
Male :     $  l    $     $   r   t

Female:    H  $    $     $   r  n    a
```

**Step 2:**

Count the remaining letters from both strings.

Count : 7

**Step 3:**

Using the count we have to iterate the string **“FLAMES”** in the following manner

```
F       L           A        M        E           S

1       2           3         4       5           6

7

(Here the count 7 ends at F ,so strike F)
```

you will get

```
$       L         A         M         E         S
```

(Again start your count from immediate next letter (it should not   already be hit out) if it is the last letter (“S”) then start from first letter “F” if ‘F” is not already hit out.

```
 $              L         A          M             E             S

 (igonre)        1         2          3              4            5

 (ignore)       6         7
```

**During counting never consider hit out letters.**

```
$          L         $               M           E         S

                                    1           2          3      

ignore     4       ignore           5           6          7
```

"s" will be hit out.

```
$            L         $           M          E        $

ignore       1         ignore      2           3       

             4         ignore      5           6 

             7
```

"L" will be hit out

```
$           $          $            M             E           $

                      ignore        1             2          ignore

ignore     ignore     ignore        3             4          ignore

                                    5             6  

                                    7
```

Finally "M" will be hit out. Then only remaining letter is "E" So albert is enemy to herbana.

**Update :**
Lettter "r" is also common in both names.I forgor to hit it out.Anyhow the process is same as explained.Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This isn't a good foundation for a successful relationship.

Comment: Thanks.But,I considered for logic. :)

Comment: 'r' is also common in both names

Comment: Oops i missed that one out.Thanks for pointing it out.I upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step1 and Step2

```
var firstLookup = firstName.ToLookup(c => c.ToLower());
var secondLookup = secondName.ToLookup(c => c.ToLower());
var allChars = firstLookup.Keys.Union(secondLookup.Keys);
int count =
(
  from c in allChars
  let firstCount = firstLookup[c].Count()
  let secondCount = secondLookup[c].Count()
  select
    firstCount < secondCount ? secondCount - firstCount :
    firstCount - secondCount
).Sum()
```

Step3 (untested)

```
List<char> word = "FLAMES".ToList();

while (word.Count > 1)
{
  int wordCount = word.Count;
  int remove = (count-1) % wordCount;
  word =
    word.Select( (c, i) => new {c, i =
      i == remove ? 0 :
      i < remove ? i + wordCount + 1 : 
      i})
    .OrderBy(x => x.i)
    .Select(x => x.c)
    .Skip(1)
    .ToList();
}

char result = word.Single();
```

Comment: Thanks David,I suspect  step three is the critical part,is won't it?

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = male.Length + female.Length - male.Intersect( female ).Count();

while (flames.Length > 1)
{
     flames = string.Join( '', flames.Where( (c,i) => i != (count % flames.Length) -1 ).ToArray() );
}
```

Comment: This neither compiles, nor gives me the letter "E" when trying with count=1, as in the example.

Comment: I didn't try to compile it since I only have my Macintosh at present.  I suspect the difference may be zero-based indices versus one-based indices in the example, though I thought I had accounted for that.  I'll look at it when I get to the office.

Answer (score 2):

That last calculation part that iterates through the flames-letters and removing one after another can be precalculated.

```
public static Char GetChar(int diff) {
    var idx = (diff - 1) % 60;
    return "efefmeaelmaafmfaflefefeemsasamfmfallslslesmsasmmaelmlaslslfs"[idx];
}
```

Some things can be done without linq... unless I totally messed something up.

Comment: How did you figure out that string? I can't see the pattern

Comment: @CasperT - took me some time, too. There is no pattern, it's pre calculated - s/he ran it for 60 possible values, and these are the results. I looked for a pattern, but couldn't simplify the loop away.

Comment: Yes, that's the 60 possible values that will repeat itself over and over again. You could probably just do a precalculation of the first thousand results if you fancy a brute force solution, and hope noone finds two names of 500 characters each... ;)

Comment: but isn't a a simple loop better than some magic string?
You'd only need to run the loop once and then save the pattern.

Comment: I ran the loop once, and that's the output. Running the loop once in code would mean you need to consume cpu resources on something that can be determined before or at compile time. Also, it would need to be calculated by every instance of the program, consuming more cpu time in total than it took for me to run the loop locally.